# React native only play store app shows error app is not authorized to use firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm developing a react-native mobile app which use firebase phone auth.
but i had a problem with generated apk on **Play Store only**, the app i download from play store show an error message

> `this app is not authorized to user firebase auth please verify that
>   the package name and sha-1 are confgured in the firebase console`

but when i send the generated apk from my laptop to my mobile it doesn't show this error.
I searched the internet and **i added the** **debug and release sha-1 to firebase console**, also i checked the package name and it is correct but the app which i download from play store doesn't work.

i used android studio and the following command  `keytool -J-Duser.language=en -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore`

to get the sha-1 and both gives the same sha-1.

any help please?

Comment: did you find the solution ever? I am stuck in same issue.

Comment: No, i didn't. my problem occurs on play store (when publishing the app to play store). i opened an issue on RNFirebase but no one replied too, please when you find a solution post it here.

Comment: I think we need to purchase any Firebase plan, then only it will work.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @RaviManiyar check the answer below because i found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

go to your google play and your publish apps from signing app you will find the md5 and sha-1 code take them and add them to firebase.
this solved the problem.